# Why are there multiple 'debug' folders in a Visual Studio 2008 project?

Tags: visual-studio

When I create a Visual C++ project named `test`, the project directory will be like this:

```
test

    test
        Debug
    
    Debug
    
    test.ncb
    
    test.sln
    
    test.suo
```

Why does it create two `Debug` directories?

Answer (score 2):

One of the folders is for the project (output files from the project)
One of the folders is for the solution (output files from all the projects in the solution)